# How to catch event on element create by javascript

Tags: jquery

I have a link create by javacript

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="view-more" start="15">View more</a>
```

(I have library jquery)

```
 $('.view-more').click(function() {
      console.log($(this).attr('start'));
 })
```

Comment: This link create before document load, thank!

Comment: missing `)` at the end also use `#` like `href='#'`

Comment: @Chiu , you *could* do that, but it would be much simpler to attach the event to an ansestor element that always exists like:  `$(document).on('click','.view-more',function(){ // code here });`

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.view-more').click(function() {
      console.log($(this).attr('start'));
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="view-more" start="15">View more</a>
```

1. Missing `)` at the end.
2. Use `#` like `href="#"`

If you are creating the links dynamically you should use event delegation like

```js
$("body").append('<a href="#" class="view-more" start="15">View more</a>')

$(document).on('click','.view-more',function() {
      console.log($(this).attr('start'));
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

1. Use `.on()` for dynamically added elements

Comment: you might also mention `.on()` since we're talking about dynamic elements, though the OP is pretty vague there

Comment: yes i will update the answer

Comment: Thank you very muck. It is what I need ($(document).on). thank you!!!!